# Is there a name for this kind of supplementary text?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/crosswords/prize/25232) is a link to a crossword published by The Guardian (UK newspaper).

As happens from time to time, the puzzle is headed by a brief note marked **Special Instructions**.

My friends and I invariably refer to that text as the *byline*, but we all agree this isn't the right word. Possibly there isn't one. I doubt there's a really common name for it, or The Guardian would have written that instead of *Special Instructions*.

Is there a more appropriate term out there?

Comment: Are you the Guardian editor?

Comment: No. Why would you think that? It's just that I often do these puzzles in company. We commonly need to mention the special instructions, which it's easy to forget about when you're concentrating on clues. One of the friends is blind, so he often says "Remind me - what's the byline again?". We just want a better word, is all.

Comment: How about 'Theme'? - Special instructions: the comments are generally light hearted, not to be taken too seriously.

Comment: @osknows: ty on both counts. I didn't really think the question was being asked seriously, but I gotta admit I didn't see the joke at the time either. And I suggest you put **theme** up as an answer, 'cos I wouldn't be surprised if that turns out to be what I'll have to go with in the end. Only problem being that these puzzles often have an implicit "theme" that's never explicitly mentioned on the page, but which we solvers refer to once we discover there *is* a theme (several answers turn out to be quotes from Shakespeare, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Why not mix the concept of *theme* and that of *hint*. Something like 'theme hint' or 'theme cue' or 'topical indication' (that's a mouthful for your blind friend I'm afraid). Just 'the cue' then, that would make it short and unambiguous...

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: *Now* we're getting somewhere! I'm gonna turn it in for now, but **cue** is doing it for me so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's an *official* name as such, but I would probably call it the [rubric](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rubric?q=rubric), by analogy to similar instructions at the top of exam papers.

Comment: I would use "rubric" too.

Comment: Yes! That slots nicely into my lexicon, thanks! I was quite attracted to **cue** - simply because of the alliteration with **clue** (usuallly this additional text functions as an extra clue). But that would have been a bit too tichy (tongue-in-cheek). **Rubric** fits the bill nicely.

Comment: Although thE guardiaN (or however they are capitalising it today) would probably use "rurbic"

Answer (score 4):

I'd say *aside* or *annotation*. If you want to *label* it, I'd use *note*.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not a byline. That just  refers to the name of the journalist who wrote a story.
I would call what you saw a form of explanatory text.

Comment: Hmm. "explanatory text" is no better than "special instructions". I was rather hoping for a single word.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it was a "hint", or a "note" or even better, ["comment":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment)

> A comment is generally a verbal or written remark often related to an added piece of information, or an observation or statement.

In this case, it could be a "Hinting comment", or just either "hint" or "comment".